Split Dates in SQL/snowflake when End_date > start date

I am trying to solve a case where we need to split the date based on start_date and end_date using SQL in Snowflake.
When ACTUAL_END_DATE > ACTUAL_START_DATE, we need to split the data. For example:
ACTUAL_START_DATE = 2024-04-11 00:00:00.000
ACTUAL_END_DATE   = 2024-04-14 12:00:00.000

Then, I need to show output as below:
ID     ACTUAL_START_DATE           ACTUAL_END_DATE
1      2024-04-11 00:00:00.000     2024-04-11 23:59:59.000
2      2024-04-12 00:00:00.000     2024-04-12 23:59:59.000
3      2024-04-13 00:00:00.000     2024-04-13 23:59:59.000
4      2024-04-14 00:00:00.000     2024-04-14 12:00:00.000

Also, if the day of the date is the same, then we display it as is. The difference between the two dates will be a maximum of 7 days or less.
I am using the below code, with the only problem being it works only when the difference is 1 day. For example, start_date is 12 and end_date is 13. In all the other scenarios, this does not work properly.
Below is the output and the query I have:
select *
    from (
    WITH
  original AS (
    SELECT distinct
    START_DATE,
    ACTUAL_START_DATE,
    ACTUAL_END_DATE,
    AGENT_NAME,
    AGENT_ID,
    BUSINESSUNIT_NAME,
    MANAGEMENTUNIT_NAME ,
    ACTUAL_ACTIVITY_CATEGORY,
    ACTIVITY_DURATION
    from
    (select distinct * FROM actual_table
     QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AGENT_ID, ACTUAL_START_DATE, ACTUAL_END_DATE, ACTUAL_ACTIVITY_CATEGORY ORDER BY START_DATE desc) = 1) order by 1 desc
    
  ),
  before_midnight AS (
    SELECT distinct 
     START_DATE,
    AGENT_NAME,
    AGENT_ID,
    BUSINESSUNIT_NAME,
    MANAGEMENTUNIT_NAME,
    ACTUAL_ACTIVITY_CATEGORY,
    ACTIVITY_DURATION,
    ACTUAL_START_DATE,
    CASE 
          WHEN DATE_PART('DAY', ACTUAL_START_DATE) < DATE_PART('DAY', ACTUAL_END_DATE) THEN
            DATEADD('second', -1, TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE (ACTUAL_END_DATE)))
         WHEN (DATE_PART('DAY', ACTUAL_START_DATE) = '31' and DATE_PART('DAY', ACTUAL_END_DATE) = '01') THEN
            DATEADD('second', -1, TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE (ACTUAL_END_DATE)))
         WHEN (DATE_PART('DAY', ACTUAL_START_DATE) = '30' and DATE_PART('DAY', ACTUAL_END_DATE) = '01') THEN
            DATEADD('second', -1, TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE (ACTUAL_END_DATE)))
          ELSE ACTUAL_END_DATE
        END AS ACTUAL_END_DATE

    FROM original
  ),
  after_midnight AS (
    SELECT distinct
     START_DATE,

    AGENT_NAME,
    AGENT_ID,
    BUSINESSUNIT_NAME,
    MANAGEMENTUNIT_NAME,
    ACTUAL_ACTIVITY_CATEGORY,
    ACTIVITY_DURATION,
     CASE 
          WHEN DATE_PART('DAY', ACTUAL_START_DATE) < DATE_PART('DAY', ACTUAL_END_DATE) THEN
            TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(ACTUAL_END_DATE))
          WHEN (DATE_PART('DAY', ACTUAL_START_DATE) = '31' and DATE_PART('DAY', ACTUAL_END_DATE) = '01') THEN
            TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(ACTUAL_END_DATE))
          WHEN (DATE_PART('DAY', ACTUAL_START_DATE) = '30' and DATE_PART('DAY', ACTUAL_END_DATE) = '01') THEN
            TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(ACTUAL_END_DATE))
          ELSE ACTUAL_START_DATE
       END AS ACTUAL_START_DATE,
    ACTUAL_END_DATE,

    FROM original
  )
SELECT 
   START_DATE,
    ACTUAL_START_DATE,
    ACTUAL_END_DATE,
    AGENT_NAME,
    AGENT_ID,
    BUSINESSUNIT_NAME,
    MANAGEMENTUNIT_NAME,
    ACTUAL_ACTIVITY_CATEGORY,
    ACTIVITY_DURATION  
    
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM before_midnight
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT * FROM after_midnight
) AS combined
) a;

Output:
OUTPUT:

ID     ACTUAL_START_DATE           ACTUAL_END_DATE
1      2024-04-11 00:00:00.000     2024-04-13 23:59:59.000
2      2024-04-14 00:00:00.000     2024-04-14 12:00:00.000



I would leverage a date dimension, if you have one.  If not, you can create one in a CTE using Snowflake's generator function and then use that to join.  The query that I came up with, which produces the output you are looking for:
with date_dim as (
    select seq4() as id, 
           row_number() over (order by id) as row_num,
           dateadd(day,row_num,'1999-12-31'::timestamp) as dat
    from TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 36500))
), data_table as (
    select seq4() as id, *
    from (values ('2024-04-11 01:00:00.000'::timestamp,'2024-04-14 12:00:00.000'::timestamp)) x (ACTUAL_START_DATE, ACTUAL_END_DATE)
)
select row_number() over (partition by dt.id order by dd.id) as id,
       case when dt.actual_start_date > dd.dat then dt.actual_start_date else dd.dat end as actual_start_date,
       case when dt.actual_end_date < dateadd(d,1,dd.dat) then dt.actual_end_date else dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(d,1,dd.dat)) end as actual_end_date
from data_table dt
join date_dim dd
  on dd.dat between date_trunc(day,dt.actual_start_date) and dt.actual_end_date;

The first CTE is the date dimension for about 100 years of dates from 2000.  The second CTE is just creating a table with your example dates in it.
The query then just joins your data to the date_dim using a between, which will burst your record out into the appropriate number of records.  Then, I just manipulate the dates for each record accordingly.
Note: I modified your example to make sure this would handle a start date that was in the middle of the day.  I think this is what you'd need.  Also, I added a way to create your id values, but not sure it's what you were looking for when you have multiple records in your table.  This should number 1 to n for each record you have in your table.
